# EAS build fails : Unable to resolve module ./aws-exports

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I am using `expo 43` with `Amplify` when i run the app in mobile using

```
expo run:android
```

I can see my application running on mobile.

But when i try to create the build for same

```
eas build -p android
```

i am getting below error

```
Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase
```

here the eas json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.46.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Here's the log for eas build

```
[stderr]   40 | import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";
Error: Unable to resolve module ./aws-exports from /root/workingdir/build/App.js: 
None of these files exist:
  * aws-exports(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * aws-exports/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  40 | import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";
  41 | import Amplify from 'aws-amplify'
> 42 | import config from './aws-exports'
```

i have the aws-exports.js in root directory and it working for expo run:android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root problem is shown in the log : EAS build can't resolve module `./aws-exports`.

There are 2 reasons for this :

- a) this file is ignored in your repository because it contains sensitive data (this is the default config made by amplify in `.gitignore`)
- b) EAS upload a copy of the repository on their servers, so because of a) `aws-exports.js` is not copied. Hence the build error.

I solve this by using the [EAS Secret](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/#adding-secrets-with-eas-cli) feature. The trick is to base64 encode the content of `aws-exports.js` in a variable, saying `AWS_EXPORTS`. This variable can be used in a pre-install hook named `eas-build-pre-install`, so we can tell EAS to decode the value and write it back in `aws-exports.js`, so the file will be available at build time.

This is done by adding these 2 scripts in `package.json` :

```
 "aws-export": "echo 'Update Expo AWS_EXPORTS secret with value: \n\n' && cat aws-exports.js |base64"
```

Run `aws-export` script, then set the encoded content via Secrets tab on Expo website, or with `eas secret:create` command. Don't forget to update the value each time you change something in amplify to reflect the local changes in `aws-exports.js` !

Then the pre-install hook will decode the value (this is automatically run by EAS) :

```
"eas-build-pre-install": "echo $AWS_EXPORTS | base64 -d > ./aws-exports.js"
```

Run the build again.

Comment: Thanks a lot @colinux the above solution works for me. I had faced few more issues after that, will share the steps in seperate answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ***colinux*** EAS upload a copy of the repository on their servers and since aws-exports is a part of .gitignore, it was not uploaded at the server and hence we have the build error. Please read ***colinux's*** answer for more details on this.

The solution here is to add these 2 lines in your package JSON.

```
1. "aws-export": "echo 'Update Expo AWS_EXPORTS secret with value: \n\n' && cat aws-exports.js |base64"
2. "eas-build-pre-install": "echo $AWS_EXPORTS | base64 -di > ./aws-exports.js"
```

**Note:** There a small change here in step 2. instead of base64 -d, we have to use base64 -di.
This is because the older cli was not able to deocde newline and other chars. You can check more details here:
[decode base64: invalid input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490728/decode-base64-invalid-input)
This part resolves the build issue i posted. I was getting few more build errors realted to `app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED`

This link should help you out in case of Duplicate resources error: [Duplicate resources error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239705/react-native-error-duplicate-resources-android)

After resolving these errors you should get a successfule build from EAS.

And in case you want an .apk file instead of .aap. Please create a dev profile as mentioned below:
[Configuring a profile to build apks](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/#configuring-a-profile-to-build-apks)

Comment: I tried your method and didn't work out for me...I added the 2 lines and still got the same error, I posted my side of  the issue I'd appreciate if you can help out in any way